# is this line in sudoers file safe to add?

Tags: sudo

Is adding this to `/etc/sudoers` safe?

```
www-data ALL=(srs) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

`srs` isn't in there so not root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you add means:

The user `www-data` is able to run any commands, only as user `srs` on all machines without entering password.

It's not unsafe as I see unless the user `srs` has some special permissions itself.

For example if you have something like:

```
srs  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

at the end of your `sudoers` file, then `www-data` can run anything as anyone as well as `srs`.

Comment: Thanks, cobbled it together from bits around the web and didnt know.